# ASP MVC3 areas dbcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, initializer

I'm a newbie to C# ASP development but I'm using it to develop a web application using MVC3.

I have created an application which has common components and have broken down the services that the site provides into 'areas'. I would like to keep each area seperate as far as possible and so have created a DbContext for the application and one for each area.

I'd like to use a database initializer to initialise each of the areas but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Is this the best architectural approach to take? If so, how do I create multiple area intializers for this configuration. If not, how would you approach this problem in C# MVC3?

Thanks in advance,

Niall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only set one DbContext for a application. You would only use diffent DbContext objects if you where to use multiple databases.

Comment: So I would have to add the database models for each area to the 'central' dbcontext class?

Comment: Yes, but you only have to add those you want to access directly from the context. all models with a reference to the models in the context  will automatically be generated.